# vba parameters not received

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to make a program that searches for specific content in cells for excel:

- rows represent hours of the day from 00:00 to 23:00
- columns represent a day of the month

The following code matches the input of the user to the content of the cells either by using the name. It can also add or skip a time interval for the event

However the following code always runs the instructions under Else even if the user inputs 2 numeric values for the 2 param fields. Some help would be appreciated:

```
pNume = paramNume
aux = ""
aux1 = paramHBegin - 1
aux2 = paramHEnd - 1

If IsNumeric(paramHBegin) And IsNumeric(paramHEnd) Then

For i = 1 To 31

        For j = aux1 To aux2

            If Cells(i + 1, j + 1) Like pNume & "*" Or Cells(i + 1, j + 1) Like "*" & pNume & "*" _
            Or Cells(i + 1, j + 1) Like "*" & pNume Then

            aux = aux + Cells(i + 1, j + 1) + " la ora " + CStr(i) + vbCrLf

            End If

        Next j
    Next i

Else

For i = 1 To 31

    For j = 1 To 24

        If Cells(i + 1, j + 1) Like pNume & "*" Or Cells(i + 1, j + 1) Like "*" & pNume & "*" _
        Or Cells(i + 1, j + 1) Like "*" & pNume Then

        aux = aux + Cells(i + 1, j + 1) + " la ora " + CStr(i) + vbCrLf

        End If

    Next j
Next i

End If

    displayInfo.Text = aux
```

Comment: Run it in debug and resolve them in the immediate window to check. We can't see what `paramHBegin` and `paramHEnd` are declared as, assuming they are not numbers you might want to use `IsNumeric(trim(paramHBegin))`.
But im not sure how you got past the `aux1 = ` commands if they are not numbers.

Comment: They are text boxes where the user inputs data and yes I will try it

Answer (score 1):

This statement 
`If IsNumeric(paramHBegin) And IsNumeric(paramHEnd) Then`
will only be true if both of the values you pass are numeric. But you wrote that *"However the following code always runs the instructions under Else even if the user inputs 2 numeric values for the 2 param fields."*

Assuming `paramHBegin` and `paramHEnd` are defined as strings, the only way I can see that happening is for one or both of the values having a character that isn't numeric. In Excel 2013 `IsNumeric` ignores carriage returns, tabs and spaces so they aren't the cause of the problem. If they are defined as objects, then you should specify the correct property of those objects.

Comment: paramHBegin and paramHEnd are not defined.. they are text boxes in a userform where the user inputs data..Also I am using excel 2007

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't try it myself, but try something like this:

```
If IsNumeric(paramHBegin.Text) And IsNumeric(paramHEnd.Text) Then
```

or this:

```
If IsNumeric(val(paramHBegin.Text)) And IsNumeric(val(paramHEnd.Text)) Then
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to handle user inputs right at the input session itself rather then passing everything forward and then trying to handle exceptions

for instance, to force (to some extent) numeric inputs you could place in the UserForm code pane what follows:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub paramHBegin_AfterUpdate()
    TextBoxValidate Me.paramHBegin
End Sub

Private Sub paramHEnd_AfterUpdate()
    TextBoxValidate Me.paramHEnd
End Sub

Private Sub paramNume_AfterUpdate()
    TextBoxValidate Me.paramNume
End Sub

Sub TextBoxValidate(ctrl As MSForms.TextBox)
    Dim number As Double

    Me.CommandButton1.Enabled = False
    With ctrl
        If Not ValidateText(.text, number) Then
            MsgBox "invalid input", vbCritical
            .SetFocus
        Else
            .text = number
            Me.CommandButton1.Enabled = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Function ValidateText(text As String, number As Double) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    number = CDbl(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(text, " ", ""))
    ValidateText = IsNumeric(number)
End Function
```

in essence:

- add an `AfterUpdate` event handler for every relevant `TextBox`
- that event handler would simply pass the validation dues to a specific sub (`TextBoxValidate()`) where you can put code to handle general `TextBox`  validation environment

  for instance I

  - disabled `CommandButton1` `button` (the "OK" one in my test)
  - call a function (`ValidateText`()) for validating the `Text` property of a `TextBox` control which would return:

    - `True` and the validated number, if the `Text` property were actually a *possible* number
    - `False` otherwise
  - if validation result is `True`:

    - update the `TextBox` with the validated number
    - enable the "OK" `Button`
  - if validation result is `False`:

    - prompt a message and return the focus to the "invalid" `TextBox`

of course you can tune all those Subs and Functions to your actual needs like:

- checking for specific text formats (with `Like` operator or - better - with `RegEx` object)
- checking for specific types ( using `Clng()` or `CInt()` or `CDate()` instead of `CDbl()` in a sort of *`TryParse()`* fashion
- changing validation rules according to each control type (`TextBox` rather than `ListBox` and so on) and property (`Text` Property rather than `Value` ...)

---

Finally

- use "&" operator instead of "+" one to concatenate strings
- `If Cells(i + 1, j + 1) Like pNume & "*" Or Cells(i + 1, j + 1) Like "*" & pNume & "*" _
          Or Cells(i + 1, j + 1) Like "*" & pNume Then`

  can be reduced to:

  `If Cells(i + 1, j + 1) Like "*" & CStr(pNume) & "*" Then`

hope all this can help

Comment: @IsraelRamirez: did you get through it?